# how to represent List<string> in database

Tags: c#

I'm trying to represent the following class in the database,

```
class Student
{
   int ID,
   string Name,
   List<String> Skills
}
```

I'm not sure how to represent Skills in my database.. Please help

Comment: add a table `Skills`, and a table `StudentSkills`.  `StudentSkills` can hold the `ID` of the student, and the `ID` of the skill, and you can join them that way.

Answer (score 4):

Since a student can have many skills and one skill can be available to many students, the relationship between student and skill is *a many to many* relationship. That being said, you could declare a table called Skills, where you could store all available skills and a table called StudentsSkills, which will hold the realationship between a skill and a student. So in the table called StudentsSkills you could have from 0 to as many as the number of skills records for a student.

Comment: And the term for a table such as StudentSkills is "junction table."